# Find average of a column when datatype is object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as shown below

How can I calculate average of values in the 'list' column?

```
new = pd.DataFrame({
                    'list' : ['0 Minute 17 Seconds', 
                              '0 Minute 50 Seconds',
                              '0 Minute 19 Seconds', 
                              '0 Minute 29 Seconds']
                    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For average in seconds use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with casting to `string`s:

```
df = new['list'].str.extract('(\d+)\s+Minute\s+(\d+)\s+Seconds')
df.columns = ['min','sec']

out = (df['min'].astype(int) * 60 + df['sec'].astype(int)).mean()
print (out)
28.75
```

Comment: Can we go the duplicate soln path? instead of creating redundant solutions Please.

Comment: @min2bro - there si dupe? Not sure, but be free find it.